# How to find out what process created a certain file after the deed has been done?

Tags: windows, windows-10, filesystems, process

I know [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/193505/is-there-a-way-to-find-out-what-process-created-certain-file) exists.

What are my options to get a hold of an application (probably malfunction in code) that creates a "bad file" like in this screenshot:

[image]

It's always exactly this file, with the exact name, and it's away for days sometimes, sometimes even longer, I seriously don't know which application is causing this crazy file and it's making me insane, I want to get rid of the application.

How can I achieve what I want on Windows 10? Can I create a fake file with the same name that tells me what process accessed it and when?

Is there some logging functions / debug I can turn on in Windows 10 for this?

Comment: Making a fake file, non-writeable, might provoke an error message from the app that tries, and then fails, to create it.

Comment: ^ like to set it to read only or remove it's permissions. while your in permissions you might see something there too.

Comment: When it will appear again I'll try this! Thanks

Comment: @Gizmo you have to make the fake file *before* it appears again; otherwise the app will succeed and you won't get any error message.